# Create an array of GImages

Tags: java

So for my final assignment I have to create a game using a split screen with a console as well as a GCanvas. I have the console all set up, i just cannot find a way to put my GImages up onto the canvas. right now the code that i think is giving me trouble is :

```
String [] cards = {
  "apple-ConvertImage.gif",
  "pear-ConvertImage.gif", 
  "banana-ConvertImage.gif", 
  "peaches-ConvertImage.gif"
};
```

and the method:

```
 private void draw(String[] cards){
   for (int i=0 ; i <= 3; i++){
     GImage card = new GImage (cards[i],0,200);
     canvas.add(card);
   }
 }
```

and I also call the method using 
`draw(cards);`

I Keep getting the attach source code error which says that it cannot find MediaTools.class

Comment: Eclipse is a development environment used to develop many different programming languages - which language is this? What is `GImage`?

Comment: I'm programming in Java, and GImage is a constructor from the acm.graphics.*; package

Comment: And `acm.graphics` is what - is that the Stanford package (which most people won't know anything about)? When using unusual packages you need to tell us exactly what they are.